# How do I stretch an image to fit the whole background (100% height x 100% width) in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, containers, stretch

I have an image that doesn't match the aspect ratio of my device's screen. I want to stretch the image so that it fully fills the screen, and I don't want to crop any part of the image.

CSS has the concept of percentages, so I could just set height and width to 100%. But it doesn't seem like Flutter has that concept, and it's bad to just hard code the height and width, so I'm stuck.

Here's what I have (I'm using a Stack since I have something in the foreground of the image):

```
Widget background = new Container(
  height: // Not sure what to put here!
  width: // Not sure what to put here!
  child: new Image.asset(
    asset.background,
    fit: BoxFit.fill, // I thought this would fill up my Container but it doesn't
  ),
);

return new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    background,
    foreground,
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 172):

To make an Image fill its parent, simply wrap it into a `FittedBox`:

```
FittedBox(
  child: Image.asset('foo.png'),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

`FittedBox` here will stretch the image to fill the space.
(Note that this functionality used to be provided by `BoxFit.fill`, but the API has meanwhile changed such that `BoxFit` no longer provides this functionality. `FittedBox` should work as a drop-in replacement, no changes need to be made to the constructor arguments.)

---

Alternatively, for complex decorations you can use a `Container` instead of an `Image` – and use `decoration`/`foregroundDecoration` fields.

To make the `Container` will its parent, it should either:

- have no child
- have `alignment` property not `null`

Here's an example that combines two images and a `Text` in a single `Container`, while taking 100% width/height of its parent:

[image]

```
Container(
  foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(
            'https://p6.storage.canalblog.com/69/50/922142/85510911_o.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.fill),
  ),
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        alignment: Alignment(-.2, 0),
        image: NetworkImage(
            'http://www.naturerights.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Taranaki-NR-post-1170x550.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
  child: Text(
    "Hello World",
    style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .display1
        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
  ),
),
```

Comment: How can I a add a fade in image widget here? I don't think we can.

Comment: Ty, I have I think newer version and I did: _SizedBox.expand(child: Image.asset("assets/bg.png", fit: BoxFit.fill))_

Comment: so why is the `fit` parameter still present in the various Image constructors? What's the use, if it has been de facto replaced by FittedBox?

Comment: For me, it didn't work with FittedBox. But @Ido 's comment to use SizedBox.expand() did work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 132):

The following will fit the image to 100% of container width while the height is constant. 
For local assets, use [AssetImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html)

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
    ),
  ),
)
```

---

#### Image fill modes:

- **Fill** - Image is stretched

  ```
  fit: BoxFit.fill
  ```

  [image]

  ---
- **Fit Height** - image kept proportional while making sure the full height of the image is shown (may overflow)

  ```
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
  ```

  [image]

  ---
- **Fit Width** - image kept proportional while making sure the full width of the image is shown (may overflow)

  ```
  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
  ```

  [image]

  ---
- **Cover** - image kept proportional, ensures maximum coverage of the container (may overflow)

  ```
  fit: BoxFit.cover
  ```

  [image]

  ---
- **Contain** - image kept proportional, minimal as possible, will reduce it's size if needed to display the entire image

  ```
  fit: BoxFit.contain
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Never use MediaQuery to make an widget fill its parent. That's not what you want

Comment: @RémiRousselet can you explain reason for that (or give me a link to that reason) .Thanks.

Comment: I will go with "fit: BoxFit.cover,". Thanks.

Comment: This deserves an extra up-vote for the awesome examples of each of the fit modes.

Answer (score 71):

Inside your Stack, you should wrap your `background` widget in a [Positioned.fill](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html).

```
return new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Positioned.fill(
      child: background,
    ),
    foreground,
  ],
);
```

Comment: thanks for this `Stack` widget overlay, I were searching for this widget in `Flutter`, by using this it is possible for me to `Show Container above Image`, cheers!

Answer (score 46):

For me, to develop for web, works fine the following:

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage('lib/images/portadaSchamann5.png'),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  height: double.infinity,
  width: double.infinity,
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
),
```

Comment: this seems to be canon too: [`SizedBox.expand`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html) uses `double.infinity` for its values too.

Answer (score 20):

Might not be exactly what the OP was looking for, but this page is where I found myself after looking for the problem, so sharing this for everyone with similar issue :)

Stack's `fit` property did the trick for my needs. Otherwise Image inside (OctoImageIn my case) was padded and providing other `Image.fit` values did not give any effect.

```dart
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand, 
  children: [
    Image(
      image: provider,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    // other irrelevent children here
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 12):

Your Question contains the first step, but you need width and height. you can get the width and height of the screen. Here is a small edit

```
//gets the screen width and height
double Width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double Height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Widget background = new Image.asset(
  asset.background,
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
  width: Width,
  height: Height,
);

return new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    background,
    foreground,
  ],
);
```

You can also use Width and Height to size other objects based on screen size.

ex: `width: Height/2, height: Height/2 //using height for both keeps aspect ratio`

Comment: `fit: BoxFit.fill,` on Image was a life saver, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

The best example for this question I found on this page:
https://flutterbeads.com/set-background-image-in-flutter/

By using BoxDecoration and DecorationImage:

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/cat2.jpg"), 
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank You, Thank you, Thank you.. I was literally banging my head on this

Answer (score 7):

I think that for your purpose [Flex](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) could work better than Container():

```
new Flex(
    direction: Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset(asset.background)
    ],
   )
```

Comment: You just saved my life - :)  Perfect for me.

Answer (score 5):

This should work,

```
Image.asset('assets/bg.jpg',fit: BoxFit.cover,),
```

Comment: This. You can also BoxFit.fitWidth, fitHeight and others.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked for me.  And since there is no accepted answer, I found the following extended my image from horizontal edge to horizontal edge:

```
Container ( width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width,
                child: 
                  Image.network(my_image_name, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth )
              )
```

Comment: This answer works when you only want to fit the image to full width without stretching it

Answer (score 4):

Visit https://youtu.be/TQ32vqvMR80
OR

For example if parent contrainer has height: 200, then

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage('url'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 3):

For filling, I sometimes use SizedBox.expand

Answer (score 3):

I set width and height of a container to double.infinity like so:

```
Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: //your child
)
```

Comment: This won't work for the child of the container, just the container.

Answer (score 3):

This will work if you want to add a fit background image in Flutter:

```
class Myname extends StatelessWidget {
  const Myname({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/aj.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Column(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can add the rest of the things inside the `Column()`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into problems with just an `FittedBox` so I wrapped my Image in an `LayoutBuilder`:

```
LayoutBuilder( 
   builder: (_, constraints) => Image(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      image: AssetImage(assets.example),
   ),
)
```

This worked like a charm and I suggest you give it a try.
*Of course you can use height instead of width, this is just what I used.*

Answer (score 1):

For me, using `Image(fit: BoxFit.fill ...)` worked when in a bounded container.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Image.asset("images/my_image.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t find answer in this post, But I found the fix:

```
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/package_bg.png',
        )),
```

This code make image fit to height on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `contentPadding`

```
ListTile(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  ...
)
```