# Flutter Stack size to sibling

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to size a stack child automatically to its largest sibling?
I.e. if I have a `Stack` with a `ListTile` and a `Container` on top, how do I make sure the `Container` covers the entire `ListTile`?

Example:

```
new Stack(children: <Widget>[
      new ListTile(
          leading: new AssetImage('foo.jpg'),
          title: new Text('Bar'),
          subtitle: new Text('yipeee'),
          isThreeLine: true,
      ),
      new Container(color: Colors.grey, child: new Text('foo'))
 ],
)
```

I tried to make it work with `Row`, `Column` and `Expanded` but am running into problems with unbounded constraints.

Is there a way to size the `Container` (or any other widget such as a `GestureDetector`) to its largest sibling in the stack?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/after_layout might be able to help you

Comment: Did nesbocay's answer not work for you? Because it did work for me.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally managed to solve it using this answer:

> Inside your Stack, you should wrap your background widget in a Positioned.fill.
>
> ```
> return new Stack(
>   children: <Widget>[
>     new Positioned.fill(
>       child: background,
>     ),
>     foreground,
>   ],
> );
> ```
>
> -- [Mary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8468400/mary), https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745479

Applying that to your question results in the following:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      leading: AssetImage('foo.jpg'),
      title: Text('Bar'),
      subtitle: Text('yipeee'),
      isThreeLine: true,
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Container(color: Colors.grey, child: Text('foo')),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Just to clarify - the widget that should be wrapped in a `Positioned.fill` is the one that should adjust its size to its sibling. Wether that's the background or foreground widget depends on your use case (the quoted answer wraps the background widget, while this answer wraps the foreground widget).

Comment: Does the trick for me. Thanks!