# How to make the children in the stack equal in height in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to make the children in the stack equal in height in flutter? The container below is the automatic height, I need to set the height of the upper container according to the height of the lower container.

**Why do I need this？**

Because I want to implement a background progress bar.

```
return Stack(
  children: [,
    Container(
      //how to auto set this widget equal height to below.
      height:?
    ),
    Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("a"),
          Text("b"),
          Text("c"),
          //maybe more widgets..
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? -[stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828082/10755967)

Comment: why not set both height like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution based on @JaisonThomas' comment.

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {                       
        return Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: constraints.maxWidth * _progress,
                color: statusColor,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("a"),
          Text("b"),
          Text("c"),
          //maybe more widgets..
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just wrap your `Stack` widget with `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

This will make each of the children of the `Stack` widget occupy the height of the largest child. So. all children will be of equal height.

As per the example you shared:

```
return IntrinsicHeight(
child: Stack(
  children: [,
    Container(
      child: SomeWidget(),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("a"),
          Text("b"),
          Text("c"),
          //maybe more widgets..
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although there is a good solution that made by 'noveleven',
I implemented by using 'addPostFrameCallback' and 'key'.

(I added a background color for distinguish Widget.)
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  double _sizeOfColumn = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        _sizeOfColumn = _key.currentContext.size.height;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          height: _sizeOfColumn,
        ),
        Container(
          key: _key,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text("a"),
              Text("b"),
              Text("c"),
              Text("a"),
              Text("b"),
              Text("c"),
              //maybe more widgets..
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but i need to use it in ListView.