# Show a big size photo with a fixed sized flutter Container with scrolling functionality

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to show a big size image inside a flutter container

`Container(
height:200,
width:200,
child:image.network('image_url',))`

- image size is not fixed it may 500,600. (but container size is fixed)
  I want user can scroll to see the rest of the picture content inside on that container.

**Updated code**

```
Container(
 height:200,
 width:200,
 child:SingleChildScrollView(
       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       child: image.network('image_url')
));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745448/how-do-i-stretch-an-image-to-fit-the-whole-background-100-height-x-100-width

Comment: "I want user can scroll to ..." so use `SinglChildScrollView`

Answer (score -2):

You can use an InteractiveViewer component ([youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg)/ [code & details](https://goo.gle/3ek2Uvm))