# flutter stretch an SVG vertically in a Stack according to the size of the Stack

Tags: flutter, stack, stretch

Attempted many things from this answer:
[How do I stretch an image to fit the whole background (100% height x 100% width) in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745448/how-do-i-stretch-an-image-to-fit-the-whole-background-100-height-x-100-width) but nothing worked. the closest I got was using Position.fill, but that stretched it both ways.

Here's my latest iteration, which seems to have no effect, the image is the same size as the image, not stretched:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => 
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
  child: Stack(children: [
    Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: <Widget>[
      SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/icons/comments/lineVerticalReply.svg',
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      ),
    ]),
    Column(children: [
      //... bunch of stuff simulated by:
      SizedBox(width: 200, height:200)
    ]),
  ]),
);
```

Things I've tried:

```
Flex in combination with Expanded
FittedBox
Containers with boxConstraints
Positioned.fill <-- closest attempt
combinations of the above, and other stuff I've forgotten
```

The issue is that the size of the `Stack` widget is determined by the siblings of the `SvgPicture` widget. so I want the SvgPicture's height to respond to the height of the stack, which is determined by the largest item in the Stack.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

specifying the 'bottom' of the positioned did what I want, which I swear I tried first, but I must have been mistaken, maybe I tried it without the fitHeight, idk:

```
 Stack(children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 19,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: 2,
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/icons/comments/lineVerticalReply.svg',
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
...
```